# Doctrine 2 result caching in Symfony with form type entity

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use APC result caching in docrine, and have filter form with type entity in all website pages and want cache this, but when I add useResultCache() to method I get exception

> Entities passed to the choice field must be managed
>
> example
>   ...->getQuery()->useResultCache(true, null, 'someindex')->getResult()

but all action without `form` with `entity type` work normally.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exception is being thrown, and what's its message?

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if You've figured out how to do it, but here's how I've done it (spent half a day figuring this out).

```
/* in FormType.php */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $items = $options['entity_repository']
        ->findItems()
        ->useResultCache(true, 3600, 'my_cache')
        ->getResult();

    $choice_list = new ObjectChoiceList($items, 'name', array(), null, 'id');
    $builder->add('item', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'MyBundle:Items',
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'choice_list' => $choice_list,
    ));
}
```